# Emulator.exe missing from android-sdk\tools

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to set the android sdk location from my eclipse preferences window but it's not letting me because it is saying that emulator.exe is missing.

I have read other questions that tell me to copy the emulator.exe into the tools directory but I don't have that file.

This is weird because my sdk and eclipse were both fresh installation so why is this file missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your antivirus detect the emulator.exe as a malware and remove the file. Some of the antivirus can restore the file deleted by itself. What is your antivirus?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was not the AV program to delete the emulator.exe.

It was deleted while the emulator was running and I have clicked for the android tools to be updated through Android Studio.

The way I have fixed it was to go to the "temp" directory where the android tools was downloaded, extract the archive and then to take the tools directory and copy it to the ~/sdk/ directory

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the files in `<android-home>/tools` in SDK go missing when you are updating your SDK platforms through SDK manager or through Eclipse(on Windows 7 with Luna) and the installations fails / you restart you machine before the installation completes[due to power failures/scheduled restarts].

This causes the tools directory contents to get erased(perhaps a part of the SDK update) and before the `<android-home>/temp/**.zip` files are extracted, I guess the files in tools are deleted for replacement. This possibly explains, why the files go missing.